Serving html using C++ - loading page error
I was trying to serve an index.html file from the current directory (I changed it to just "Hello" for testing purposes). I see the page for a split second and then it just gives me this:

The connection was reset


The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

I did try everything they suggested, didn't work, and I can't get enough docs about this specific topic.
Here's the server.cpp:
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

void handleClient(SOCKET acceptSocket) {
    std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nHello";

    int bytesSent = send(acceptSocket, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0);
    if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "Error sending data to client: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Served 'Hello' to client." << std::endl;
    }

    closesocket(acceptSocket);
}

int main() {
    SOCKET serverSocket, acceptSocket;
    const int PORT = 55555;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WORD wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    if (wsaerr != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Winsock dll not found." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Winsock dll was found!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << std::endl;
    }

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr << "Error at socket()." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Socket() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }

    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &service.sin_addr.s_addr);
    service.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "bind() failed." << std::endl;
        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << "bind() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }

    if (listen(serverSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "listen() error listening on socket." << std::endl;
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << "listen() is OK!, waiting for connections.." << std::endl;
    }

    while (true) {
        acceptSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (acceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr << "accept failed." << std::endl;
            std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(serverSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }
        std::cout << "Client connected.." << std::endl;

        handleClient(acceptSocket);
    }

    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

I sure didn't expect this error after seeing the page for a split second.

also, i did try without the closesocket, i did try with no while loop (just one client), i did try threading none of them worked

For HTTP/1.1 you need to send the Connection: close header if you want to close the connection.

Also, have you checked what happens in the server when you get that error on the client?

Note: You can't say "Served 'Hello' to client." if bytesSent != SOCKET_ERROR. The return value of send is SOCKET_ERROR or the number of bytes written to the transmit buffer. The latter may or may not be the whole message you intended to send if the transmit buffer fills up. Worse, data in the send buffer might never be successfully sent for a wide variety of reasons that send can't tell you about because send's job ends when data is queued up for sending. Really picky stuff, network programming.

The server needs to tell the client how it's supposed to know the response has been fully received. Most common are Content-Length header if the server knows the size up front, or Transfer-Encoding: chunked if the server does not. For compatibility with HTTP/1.0, the server may specify Connection: close header and then simply close the connection at the end of the response; this is not recommended as the client then has no way of telling whether the response arrived in full or the connection dropped midway through, and would mis-interpret incomplete response as success.

Thank you guys for the replies the problem was the missing content-length and transfer-encoding headers and i will check "bytesSent" in the finalized version i just didn't include it in while testing thank to all the replies

The problem is that you are not telling the client (browser) when the response is finished.  You MUST send either:

a Content-Length header specifing the actual number of bytes being sent.

a Transfer-Encoding: chucked header, followed by chunks of data, terminated by a 0-length chunk.


Also, since you are closing the socket after sending the response, you should send a Connection: close header so the client knows to close their end of the connection when the response is finished.
Also, send() is not guaranteed to send as many bytes as you ask, it may send less, so you need to call send() in a loop until all bytes are actually sent.
Try something more like this:
void handleClient(SOCKET acceptSocket) {
    std::string response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                           "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                           "Content-Length: 5\r\n" // <-- ADD THIS!
                           "Connection: close\r\n" // <-- ADD THIS!
                           "\r\n"
                           "Hello";

    const char *data = response.c_str();
    size_t size = response.size();
    while (size > 0) {
        int bytesSent = send(acceptSocket, data, size, 0);
        if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cerr << "Error sending data to client: " << err << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        data += bytesSent;
        size -= bytesSent;
    }

    if (size == 0)
        std::cout << "Served 'Hello' to client." << std::endl;

    closesocket(acceptSocket);
}

Read the HTTP 1.1 protocol spec, RFC 2616, and its successors RFCs 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234, and 7235.  Pay particular attention to RFC 2616 Section 4.4: Message Length and RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3: Message Body Length.

Perfect yeah it worked, thank you
