net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when trying to fetch/getting data from localhost http server
I got a http server in C++ running on my localhost to get some data transfered to my electron react frontend. Unfortunately I run into heavy issues and I tried googling all day & night. It uses kind of a dynamic port assignement. The server is definitly running, as I can curl the response and I can open the generated json data in firefox (not in Chrome, what makes me think it´s an electron issue).
I get the following error in my dev tool for port 8080, which is definitly running:

Trying to fetch data from http://localhost:8080/simdata
GET http://localhost:8080/simdata net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

For the not used ports I get:

GET http://localhost:8083/simdata net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Heres the c++ creating the server:
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "SimConnect.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

HANDLE hSimConnect = NULL;

enum EVENT_ID {
    EVENT_SIM_START,
    EVENT_SIM_STOP,
    EVENT_ENGINE_START,
    EVENT_ENGINE_STOP,
};

enum DATA_REQUEST_ID {
    DATA_REQUEST_ID,
};

struct PositionStruct {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;
};

struct AircraftDataStruct {
    bool isEngineRunning;
    bool isOnGround;
    PositionStruct position;
    bool engineCombustion[2]; 
};

AircraftDataStruct g_aircraftData = {
    false, 
    false, 
    {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, 
    {false, false}  
};

bool g_dataUpdated = false;

// Define standard ports to try
const int STANDARD_PORTS[] = { 8080, 8081, 8082, 8083, 8084 };
const int NUM_STANDARD_PORTS = sizeof(STANDARD_PORTS) / sizeof(STANDARD_PORTS[0]);

void CALLBACK SimConnectDispatchCallback(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData, void* pContext)
{
    switch (pData->dwID)
    {
    case SIMCONNECT_RECV_ID_SIMOBJECT_DATA:
    {
        SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA* pObjData = (SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA*)pData;
        if (pObjData->dwRequestID == DATA_REQUEST_ID)
        {
            if (pObjData->dwDefineID == DATA_REQUEST_ID)
            {
                g_aircraftData.isOnGround = *(DWORD*)&pObjData->dwData;
                g_aircraftData.position.latitude = *(double*)((char*)&pObjData->dwData + sizeof(DWORD));
                g_aircraftData.position.longitude = *(double*)((char*)&pObjData->dwData + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(double));
                g_aircraftData.position.altitude = *(double*)((char*)&pObjData->dwData + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(double) * 2);
                g_aircraftData.engineCombustion[0] = *(DWORD*)((char*)&pObjData->dwData + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(double) * 3);
                g_aircraftData.engineCombustion[1] = *(DWORD*)((char*)&pObjData->dwData + sizeof(DWORD) + sizeof(double) * 3 + sizeof(DWORD));
                g_aircraftData.isEngineRunning = (g_aircraftData.engineCombustion[0] || g_aircraftData.engineCombustion[1]);

                g_dataUpdated = true;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void InitSimConnect()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (SUCCEEDED(SimConnect_Open(&hSimConnect, "SimBridge", NULL, 0, 0, 0)))
    {
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "SIM ON GROUND", "Bool", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_INT32);
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "PLANE LATITUDE", "Degrees", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_FLOAT64);
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "PLANE LONGITUDE", "Degrees", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_FLOAT64);
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "PLANE ALTITUDE", "Feet", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_FLOAT64);
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "GENERAL ENG COMBUSTION:1", "Bool", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_INT32);
        hr = SimConnect_AddToDataDefinition(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, "GENERAL ENG COMBUSTION:2", "Bool", SIMCONNECT_DATATYPE_INT32);
        hr = SimConnect_RequestDataOnSimObject(hSimConnect, DATA_REQUEST_ID, DATA_REQUEST_ID, SIMCONNECT_OBJECT_ID_USER, SIMCONNECT_PERIOD_SECOND);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI HttpServerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    int portIndex = 0;
    bool socketCreated = false;

    while (!socketCreated && portIndex < NUM_STANDARD_PORTS)
    {
        listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        sockaddr_in service;
        service.sin_family = AF_INET;
        service.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK); 
        service.sin_port = htons(STANDARD_PORTS[portIndex]);

        if (bind(listenSocket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&service), sizeof(service)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            socketCreated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            closesocket(listenSocket);
            portIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (!socketCreated)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(listenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            closesocket(listenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        char recvbuf[512];
        int recvbuflen = 512;
        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            continue;
        }
        std::string jsonResponse = "{";
        jsonResponse += "\"isEngineRunning\": " + std::string(g_aircraftData.isEngineRunning ? "true" : "false") + ",";
        jsonResponse += "\"isOnGround\": " + std::string(g_aircraftData.isOnGround ? "true" : "false") + ",";
        jsonResponse += "\"position\": {\"latitude\": " + std::to_string(g_aircraftData.position.latitude) + ",";
        jsonResponse += "\"longitude\": " + std::to_string(g_aircraftData.position.longitude) + ",";
        jsonResponse += "\"altitude\": " + std::to_string(g_aircraftData.position.altitude) + "}";
        jsonResponse += "}";
        std::string httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        httpResponse += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
        httpResponse += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(jsonResponse.length()) + "\r\n";
        httpResponse += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n";  // Allow any origin
        httpResponse += "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS\r\n";
        httpResponse += "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type\r\n";
        httpResponse += "\r\n";
        httpResponse += jsonResponse;
        send(clientSocket, httpResponse.c_str(), static_cast<int>(httpResponse.length()), 0);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
    }
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    InitSimConnect();

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, HttpServerThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, SimConnectDispatchCallback, NULL);

        // Check if data has been updated
        if (g_dataUpdated)
        {
            g_dataUpdated = false; 
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}


And heres the React code, which handles the request to the server:
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';

const ports = [8080, 8081, 8082, 8083, 8084];

interface SimDataContextProps {
  data: any;
  error: string | null;
  refreshData: () => void;
}

interface SimDataProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const SimDataContext = createContext<SimDataContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const SimDataProvider: React.FC<SimDataProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const fetchSimData = async () => {
    for (let port of ports) {
      try {
        console.log(`Trying to fetch data from http://localhost:${port}/simdata`);
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:${port}/simdata`);
        if (response.ok) {
          const jsonData = await response.json();
          console.log(`Successfully fetched data from port ${port}:`, jsonData);
          setData(jsonData);
          setError(null); 
          return;
        } else {
          console.error(`Network response was not ok for port ${port}`);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error fetching from port ${port}:`, err);
      }
    }
    setError('Failed to fetch data from all ports.');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSimData(); 
  }, []);

  return (
    <SimDataContext.Provider value={{ data, error, refreshData: fetchSimData }}>
      {children}
    </SimDataContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useSimData = () => {
  const context = useContext(SimDataContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useSimData must be used within a SimDataProvider');
  }
  return context;
};


So far, I tried setting up 127.0.0.1 instead of using localhost, didn´t help. I also tried to allowInsecureContent and playing around with different CORS settings. I also tried to disable the cache.
Thanks for your help!

For the not used ports I get: >GET http://localhost:8083/simdata net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Please clarify  what you mean here, because on the most direct read you seem to be asking  "Why do I get connection refused if I try to connect to a pointer no one is listening on?" This is the expected behaviour if a firewall isn't dropping the connection attempts.

Could you maybe have a local firewall active that is rejecting or dropping the connection?

@user4581301 Just quoted that part to clarify, that there´s a difference between the running port and the ones not being used.

@JesperJuhl Note quite sure, but as it is working in my browser or when trying to curl, there shouldn´t be any firewall restrictions, right?

What happens if you let the client close the connection? It sure looks like the client wants to keep talking, and no one told it that it couldn't At least in the old days, like the 1990s, you needed to put a Connection: close in the header if you were going to closesocket(clientSocket); at the server after sending the response. I haven't done dinkie-doo with HTTP in decades, and very little of it back then, so I don't know if that's still necessary (or if it ever really was I was still pretty much in my cluelessly hacking phase back then).

Here is a recent question that's very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78747496/4581301
